# Historising project data

Tags: r, data.table, lubridate

I regularly have the problem that I have data describing the exact change of a state (in this case a project phase) and I want to historise this data.

That means I want to be able to describe at some point in the past in which phase which project was.

Lets use this test data:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

df = structure(list(Project = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", 
                            "C", "C", "D", "D"), Date = structure(c(18659, 18748, 18687, 
                                                                    18718, 18748, 18871, 18718, 18718, 18779, 18659, 18840), class = "Date"), 
                Phase = c("Init", "P2O", "Init", "P2O", "Build", "Doc", "Init", 
                          "P2O", "Build", "Init", "P2O")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                              "data.frame"))

df[, Date:=ceiling_date(as.Date(Date, format="%d.%m.%Y"), "month")]
```

They look like:

```
    Project       Date Phase
Project       Date Phase
 1:       A 2021-03-01  Init
 2:       A 2021-06-01   P2O
 3:       B 2021-04-01  Init
 4:       B 2021-05-01   P2O
 5:       B 2021-06-01 Build
 6:       B 2021-10-01   Doc
 7:       C 2021-05-01  Init
 8:       C 2021-05-01   P2O
 9:       C 2021-07-01 Build
10:       D 2021-03-01  Init
11:       D 2021-09-01   P2O
```

Now I want to create a table which has for each Phase a Col and for each Date a Row.

I tried:

```
> dcast(df, Date~Phase, fun=length)[order(Date)]
         Date Build Doc Init P2O
1: 2021-03-01     0   0    2   0
2: 2021-04-01     0   0    1   0
3: 2021-05-01     0   0    1   2
4: 2021-06-01     1   0    0   1
5: 2021-07-01     1   0    0   0
6: 2021-09-01     0   0    0   1
7: 2021-10-01     0   1    0   0
```

But here is a big mistake.
Let's take a look just at project A.

```
Project       Date Phase
 1:       A 2021-03-01  Init
 2:       A 2021-06-01   P2O
```

Project A got into the "Init" phase on 01.03.2021 and "P2O" on 01.06.2021. In the current logic, this would look like :

```
         Date Build Doc Init P2O
1: 2021-03-01     0   0    1   0
4: 2021-06-01     0   0    0   1
```

But that is wrong. Between March and June this project was still in Init, so correctly this should be like:

```
         Date Build Doc Init P2O
1: 2021-03-01     0   0    1   0
2: 2021-04-01     0   0    1   0
3: 2021-05-01     0   0    1   0
4: 2021-06-01     0   0    0   1
```

Has anybody an idea how I could solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```r
dfwide <- dcast(df, Project + Date ~ Phase, fun = length)
merge(
  dfwide,
  dfwide[, .(Date = seq(min(Date), max(Date), by = "month")), by = .(Project)],
  by = c("Project", "Date"), all = TRUE
)[order(Date),
  ][, setNames(nafill(.SD, type = "locf"), names(.SD)), by = .(Project)]
#     Project       Date Build   Doc  Init   P2O
#      <char>     <Date> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#  1:       A 2021-03-01     0     0     1     0
#  2:       A 2021-04-01     0     0     1     0
#  3:       A 2021-05-01     0     0     1     0
#  4:       A 2021-06-01     0     0     0     1
#  5:       D 2021-03-01     0     0     1     0
#  6:       D 2021-04-01     0     0     1     0
#  7:       D 2021-05-01     0     0     1     0
#  8:       D 2021-06-01     0     0     1     0
#  9:       D 2021-07-01     0     0     1     0
# 10:       D 2021-08-01     0     0     1     0
# 11:       D 2021-09-01     0     0     0     1
# 12:       B 2021-04-01     0     0     1     0
# 13:       B 2021-05-01     0     0     0     1
# 14:       B 2021-06-01     1     0     0     0
# 15:       B 2021-07-01     1     0     0     0
# 16:       B 2021-08-01     1     0     0     0
# 17:       B 2021-09-01     1     0     0     0
# 18:       B 2021-10-01     0     1     0     0
# 19:       C 2021-05-01     0     0     1     1
# 20:       C 2021-06-01     0     0     1     1
# 21:       C 2021-07-01     1     0     0     0
#     Project       Date Build   Doc  Init   P2O
```

Same without the literal `merge` (though we're just using a `data.table`-left-join instead)

```r
dfwide[
  dfwide[, .(Date = unique(c(seq(min(Date), max(Date), by = "month"), max(Date)))), by = .(Project)],
  on = .(Project, Date)][order(Date),
  ][, setNames(nafill(.SD, type = "locf"), names(.SD)), by = .(Project)]
```

The use of `unique(c(..., max(Date)))` is to ensure that the max date is always used/preserved; if any of `seq(.)` falls short of the max date without landing on it, then the max date may not be included. When we used `merge(.., all=TRUE)` this wasn't a problem, since it would be preserved anyway, but using a left-join, it might be omitted. (Not in this data, though. I'm just being defensive.)